# symfony 3 routing with annotations + locale listener - how to avoid duplicate "requirements" for every route?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Clean setup of Symfony 3 framework, added locale listener from here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html

Example action code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/foo/")
 * @Route("/{_locale}/foo/", name="foo", requirements={"_locale"="en|ru|tk"})
 */
public function fooAction(Request $request)
{
    return new Response('true');
}
```

This syntax has to be repeated for every action. Is there a way to make it less verbose without using a Bundle? I'd like the `requirements` portion to reside in a config somewhere, if possible.

Ideally, I would like to move the `defaults={"_locale"="en"}, requirements={"_locale"="%allowed_locales%"}` part inside the Locale Listener, but from what I've tried, it seems the listener is called after the route has been matched, and so that is not possible, which is really a shame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, check out [How to Use Service Container Parameters in your Routes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/service_container_parameters.html) which is linked from [The Locale and the URL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#the-locale-and-the-url) in the Symfony Translations documentation, and states:

> Read How to Use Service Container Parameters in your Routes to learn how to avoid hardcoding the _locale requirement in all your routes.

You can essentially set those routes in a global parameter like so:

```
# app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    app.locales: en|ru|tk
```

Then in your route annotations do the following:

```
/**
 * @Route("/foo/")
 * @Route("/{_locale}/foo/", name="foo", requirements={"_locale"="%app.locales%"})
 */
public function fooAction(Request $request)
{
    return new Response('true');
}
```

I'm not sure why the documentation only shows that for defining routes in YAML  / XML / PHP but it should work just the same using annotations.

Comment: Well that's still quite verbose. I added the parameter and put it as an argument to the LocaleListener constructor, then, inside the onKernelRequest() method, put the following check: `if (in_array($locale, $this->allowedLocales)) {
                $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
            } else {
                
            }`. I am not sure what to put in the ELSE section though...
This way I can avoid putting the requirements in every @Route annotation.

Comment: You're still eliminating having to manually add the same locales for every route though, so if you ever add a new translation you'll only have to update that in one place rather than in every route of your project.

Comment: You could also add a listener that after the locale is determined, check if it's in your configured value, and if not throw an exception...but I'm not sure the tradeoff of verbosity is worth it considering you are still keeping that second line with the _locale anyway.

Comment: Welp, adding the check in the listener didn't work for some reason, all routes just went to the index route without the `requirements`... Sucks.

Comment: Can you post the listener you tried? Given the way the locale works you'd have to listen on event that occurs after the locale has already determined...like maybe listen on the controller instead of the kernel

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jurchiks/7d0c890c43639dd6cac6
With this code, http://127.0.0.1:8000/vip/ returns "index_vip"; it returns in the listener on line 24 and considers the _locale to be the "vip" portion, not the implied language. If I put the VIP route first, then it works, but that's just backwards. If I simply put the requirements in every route, then the ordering doesn't matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101712/discussion-between-jason-roman-and-jurchiks).